# Using Timestamps to Combine 3 Identical Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, timestamp

I have an Access database that is used by 3 separate people offsite; this offsite location does not have a network link (nor can it).

I have three identical databases and thus three identical tables. Each user fills in information using the same Primary keys. For this 'food evaluation' example:

```
Item       |      Color       | Timestamp

PERSON 1 (first database)
Carrot     |     Orange       | 2012-12-21 13:00:00
Watermelon |     Red          | 2012-12-21 19:00:00 <--
Blueberry  |     Blue         | 2012-12-21 17:00:00 <--

PERSON 2 (second database)
Carrot     |     Yellow       | 2012-12-21 15:00:00 <--
Apple      |     Green        | 2012-12-21 15:00:00 <--

PERSON 3 (third database)
Watermelon |     Green        | 2012-12-21 11:00:00 
Apple      |     Red          | 2012-12-21 14:00:00
Orange     |     Orange       | 2012-12-21 15:00:00 <--
```

I need to output a table:

```
Blueberry  |     Blue         | 2012-12-21 17:00:00
Watermelon |     Red          | 2012-12-21 19:00:00
Carrot     |     Yellow       | 2012-12-21 15:00:00
Apple      |     Green        | 2012-12-21 15:00:00
Orange     |     Orange       | 2012-12-21 15:00:00
```

So, based on timestamp, I need to choose only ONE of the duplicates but also have all of the non-duplicates (Item is a Primary, Unique Key). I just can't for the life of me get the SQL for this..
Using

```
SELECT Item, Color, MAX(timestamp) 
FROM (SELECT ... FROM first 
UNION SELECT ... FROM second
UNION SELECT ... FROM third)
GROUP BY Item, Color
```

But since it MUST group on Color to get a MAX function, it still creates index violations.

So.. how do I get this output?

Comment: Interesting.. but if number of offsites increase then what will you do?

Comment: I'm using a VBA script which does a lot of things dynamically; for instance there are actually around 20 tables done this way; I can loop through them, joining the databases with Union queries (just loop more Unions into the SQL if I need to). It's not ideal by far, but due to a bunch of wants of the client, this is how it needs to be updated. I'm just not skilled enough with SQL to figure this out. Originally we had just told the users "make sure you don't duplicate what the other does", but users.. not always listening.

Comment: In which way do you - or do you want to - decide which of the duplicate data is the winning one? Is it latest timestamp?

Comment: So are you receiving an email with updated table data from each offsite? Then you insert them into central database? Finally output a sheet from central database and send this up to date sheet to each offsite? where offsite click a button to insert the new sheet and update their database instance? Just curious to know as it seems very tedious - specially to manage change control/data consistency...

Comment: @Nico Yes, the plan is to use timestamps (which are changed via a macro on the tables). This way, if a user returns to an item (even if a different user initially entered it), the latest edits will take precedence (say if your apples turn brown..).

Comment: @bonCodigo It's actually that three tablet PCs are returned to the office at the end of the day; the three tablets are then synced over the network using some scripts so that each one has a full database the next morning (so that each user can see what has been done previously, helps avoid SOME duplication).

Comment: The actual application is surveying some things; that's why some of the same items have different values; the survey is (somewhat) subjective, so if the 2nd user doesn't know what the 1st user is doing that day, they may have overlapping, conflicting data; the conflict is what I need to resolve (as identical entries are no problem, it's the conflicts that throw key errors in the Union)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring Color initially, just trying to find the latest Timestamp for each Item.  So you must write a query that does only that, then you can JOIN it with the full table.

```
select a.Item, a.Color, a.Timestamp

from
(SELECT ... FROM first 
UNION SELECT ... FROM second
UNION SELECT ... FROM third) a

inner join

(SELECT Item, MAX(timestamp) as MaxTime
FROM (SELECT ... FROM first 
UNION SELECT ... FROM second
UNION SELECT ... FROM third) z
GROUP BY Item) b

on a.Item = b.Item and a.Timestamp = b.MaxTime
```

Comment: There we go.. this is what I was trying to wrap my head around for the last few days. I'll give this a try, it seems to me like it should work.

Comment: Nope.. it seems to select non-identical entries (not just Item, but if Color is different it outputs both). It puts the MaxTime correctly, but actually just tacks that field onto the end of the incorrect (duplicate) row.

Comment: I don't have a DB to test on... what do you get when you just run the second query (the one after the inner join) on its own? -- you should be getting the 5 rows in the desired output, just without the color.

Comment: Yes indeed. It has something to do with the fact that there are multiple Items with the same key returned from the query before the inner join, and since those keys do exist in the second query, it joins them all. Somehow it needs to know which of the three tables it came from?

Comment: If the second query only returns 5 rows (I believe that is what you mean by "Yes indeed"), then an INNER JOIN can only return 5 at most... unless you have some rows with the same Item/Timestamp combination???

Comment: I do have rows like that, but it's essentially returning ALL non-distinct rows at this point (in my own small sample data of 4 items, each table has all 4 items, but Item1 has different Colors in each table), it returns 6 rows (where it should return the four returned in the inner join query). It's actually returning the 'exact duplicate' rows as it should, but improperly handling the conflicts.

Comment: works ok in the SQL Fiddle provided by @boncodigo... your comments make it sound like your actual data is different than the sample you provided.  If you have Apple/green/18:00 and Apple/red/18:00, you haven't told us what the desired output is.

Comment: Not in practice. And that SQL won't work in Access. HOWEVER, your edit adding the join on timestamp worked! I also have no idea what the output should be.. hopefully (since the timestamp is seconds), this won't happen (the odds are VERY low). I'll try turning off the macros and doing this on purpose though, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: It returns both (much as it did before the join on timestamp), having additional columns (a.ID and b.ID). However, in this case, when inserting, "An entry is lost due to key violations" and only inserts one. I really don't care which one, so this works for me.

Comment: the only edit was adding the z to name the subquery... didn't change the join.  Your comment mentioned "exact duplicates," not sure what you mean there if odds of same timestamp are very low.

Comment: I missed the join on timestamp the first time... that would be my mistake, sorry, should have been solved several comments ago. It just means that two users would be doing the same Item at the PRECISE same time, AND put in different values for the same Item. The odds of that are very low.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you estimated results:

```
create table t1 ( food nvarchar(20), color nvarchar(10), timestamp datetime );
create table t2 ( food nvarchar(20), color nvarchar(10), timestamp datetime );
create table t3 ( food nvarchar(20), color nvarchar(10), timestamp datetime );

insert into t1 values 
( 'Carrot', 'Orange', '2012-12-21T13:00:00' ), 
( 'Watermelon', 'Red', '2012-12-21T19:00:00' ), 
( 'Blueberry', 'Blue', '2012-12-21T17:00:00' );

insert into t2 values 
( 'Carrot', 'Yellow', '2012-12-21T15:00:00' ), 
( 'Apple', 'Green', '2012-12-21T15:00:00' );

insert into t3 values 
( 'Watermelon', 'Green', '2012-12-21T11:00:00' ), 
( 'Apple', 'Red', '2012-12-21T14:00:00' ), 
( 'Orange', 'Orange', '2012-12-21T15:00:00' );

with "data"
as 
(
    select * from t1 
    union all select * from t2 
    union all select * from t3
)
, "maxdata"
as
(
    select
        *,
        latest = MAX( "timestamp" ) over ( partition by "food" )
    from
        data
)
select 
    "food", "color", "timestamp"
from 
    maxdata
where
    "timestamp" = "latest"
```

**@edit:** overread "ms access" - this one would be for tsql. sorry for that. nevertheless, perhaps you can use the query to transform it in valid syntax for access.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but this seems much the same as @ExactaBox's code when translated.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

One great thing about MS Access is the query on a query. You may save the union into a query. treat it as your main table. Another query that is grouped by item and max date. The join them.

Or make second query to return only max dates and use distinct item with `IN` operator ;-)

---

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f609f/6)

The answer is in ANSI SQL , so you may incorporate into MS ACCESS. All you need is a union and then group it out :)

Query:

```
select x.*, max(x.TimeStamp) 
from (
select * from person1
union all
select * from person2
union all
select * from person3) as x
group by x.Item
order by x.TimeStamp asc
;
```

Results:

```
ITEM        COLOR   MAX(X.TIMESTAMP)
Carrot      Orange  December, 21 2012 15:00:00+0000
Apple       Green   December, 21 2012 15:00:00+0000
Orange      Orange  December, 21 2012 15:00:00+0000
Blueberry   Blue    December, 21 2012 17:00:00+0000
Watermelon  Red     December, 21 2012 19:00:00+0000
```

Comment: I think that will cause an error in Access, because Color is not being aggregated.  I may be wrong...

Comment: Indeed it will; you cannot aggregate with * in the SELECT (in Access). Although I'm wondering if there's something in this order by.. maybe using "choose the first occurrence of the key in the output of this query" sort of deal.

Comment: @StuckAtWork could you please give this a go in MS ACCESS and comment please.

Comment: @bonCodigo "Cannot group on fields selected with *". When replacing * with the relevant fields, "Query does not include Color as part of the aggregate function"

Comment: Yup entire MICROSOFT package (SQL server, access) has that *feature* ;-)  then for now you gotta take the long path.

Comment: @StuckAtWork try the second method with `IN` operator. It is an alternative method.